Error undefined variable en parámetro por defecto de componente - Laravel 11
Tengo el siguiente error al entrar a mi sistema subido a producción:

Dicho error únicamente me ocurre cuando lo subo al hosting y no en local que me funcione perfectamente. Se  trata de una variable por defecto que tengo en un componente de laravel. A continuación adjunto el código de la clase y de la vista:
Alert.php
<?php

namespace App\View\Components;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Illuminate\View\Component;

class Alert extends Component
{
public $id;
public $text;
public $type;
public $confirm;
public $action;
public $method;

/**
 * Create a new component instance.
 */
public function __construct($id, $text, $type, $confirm, $method, $action='')
{
    $this->id = $id;
    $this->text = $text;
    $this->type = $type;
    $this->confirm = $confirm;
    $this->action = $action;
    $this->method = $method;
}

/**
 * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
 */
public function render(): View|Closure|string
{
    return view('components.alert');
}
}

alert.blade.php
@if(!isset($color) || $color == '')
    {{ $color = 'green' }}
@endif

<div id="{{ $id }}" tabindex="-1" class="hidden overflow-y-auto overflow-x-hidden fixed top-0 right-0 left-0 z-50 justify-center items-center w-full md:inset-0 h-[calc(100%-1rem)] max-h-full">
    <div class="relative p-4 w-full max-w-md max-h-full">
        <div class="relative bg-white rounded-lg shadow dark:bg-gray-700">
            <button type="button"
                class="absolute top-3 end-2.5 text-gray-400 bg-transparent hover:bg-gray-200 hover:text-gray-900 rounded-lg text-sm w-8 h-8 ms-auto inline-flex justify-center items-center dark:hover:bg-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white"
                data-modal-hide="{{ $id }}">
                <svg class="w-3 h-3" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 14 14">
                    <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="m1 1 6 6m0 0 6 6M7 7l6-6M7 7l-6 6" />
                </svg>
                <span class="sr-only">Close modal</span>
            </button>
            <div class="p-4 md:p-5 text-center">
                <svg class="mx-auto mb-4 text-gray-400 w-12 h-12 dark:text-gray-200" aria-hidden="true" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 20 20">
                    @if ($type === 'success')
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 11V6m0 8h.01M19 10a9 9 0 1 1-18 0 9 9 0 0 1 18 0Z" />
                    @elseif ($type === 'error')
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 11V6m0 8h.01M19 10a9 9 0 1 1-18 0 9 9 0 0 1 18 0Z" />
                    @elseif ($type === 'warning')
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 11V6m0 8h.01M19 10a9 9 0 1 1-18 0 9 9 0 0 1 18 0Z" />
                    @else
                        <path stroke="currentColor" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M10 11V6m0 8h.01M19 10a9 9 0 1 1-18 0 9 9 0 0 1 18 0Z" />
                    @endif
                </svg>
                <h3 class="mb-5 text-lg font-normal text-gray-500 dark:text-gray-400">{{ $text }}</h3>
                @if ($confirm == 'true')
                    <form id="form-{{ $id }}" action="{{ $action }}" method="POST">
                        @csrf
                        @method($method)

                        <button type="submit"
                            class="text-white bg-{{ $color }}-600 dark:bg-{{ $color }}-600 hover:bg-{{ $color }}-800 focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-{{ $color }}-300 dark:focus:ring-{{ $color }}-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm inline-flex items-center px-5 py-2.5 text-center">
                            Si, estoy seguro
                        </button>
                        <button data-modal-hide="{{ $id }}" type="button"
                            class="py-2.5 px-5 ms-3 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 focus:outline-none bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-100 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">No,
                            cancelar</button>
                    </form>
                @else
                    <button data-modal-hide="{{ $id }}" type="button"
                        class="py-2.5 px-5 text-sm font-medium text-gray-900 focus:outline-none bg-white rounded-lg border border-gray-200 hover:bg-gray-100 hover:text-blue-700 focus:z-10 focus:ring-4 focus:ring-gray-100 dark:focus:ring-gray-700 dark:bg-gray-800 dark:text-gray-400 dark:border-gray-600 dark:hover:text-white dark:hover:bg-gray-700">OK</button>
                @endif
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

Codigo donde se llama el componente
<!-- Delete User Alert -->
<x-alert id="delete-user-alert" text="¿Está seguro de dar de baja al usuario?" type="warning" confirm="true" method="delete">
    <x-slot:color>red</x-slot:color>
</x-alert>

<!-- Reactivate User Alert -->
<x-alert id="reactivate-user-alert" text="¿Está seguro de reactivar al usuario?" type="warning" confirm="true" method="patch">
    <x-slot:color>green</x-slot:color>
</x-alert>

He visto que puede ser porque el nombre de la clase no esta en CamelCase, ya lo cambie y sigue igual. Limpie cache de vista, hice composer autoload y tampoco nada, limpie todos los caches de la aplicación y tampoco nada, sigue sin reconocer la variable.

as intentando hacer un: action="{{ $action ?? '' }}"

Haciendo ese si funcionó, pero sabes porque no toma el valor por default declarado en la clase? Siempre hay que ponerle una protección en caso de que no le pase esa variable?

si colocaras el codigo donde la llamas podrias decirte, ser programador no me hace adivino!

Ahí agregue el código donde se llama, pido disculpas. Lo extraño es que en local en ningún momento da error, solo cuando se lo subió a producción.

se ve claramente que no le pasas el action :v y en constructor esta seteado como string vacio si no se envia un parametro...

Justamente ese es el comportamiento que estoy buscando, que sea un parametro opcional del componente que al no pasarle nada se setee con vacio, quizas me este faltando algo mas. Pero el codigo tal cual asi en local funciona

No se por que no te funciona, por lo que dices, por diferencias entre tu hosting y tu entorno local. Fijate que en la documentscion dice que los datos que no son necedsrios para que el componente funcione, se lo puedes pasar como atributos https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/blade#component-attributes

Creo que podes definir la propiedad y asignarle el valor por defecto public $attributes = ['action' => 'JohnDoe'];
